# Why isn't my view updating when changing the model of different directive scopes but bounded (what appears to be) correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a plunkr with the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/t2884MO6su9mv5XDQMNu?p=preview

What I'm trying to do is create a directive that goes in an a text box and makes suggestions as you type. Just like the typeahead widget of the angularui team. I don't use theirs because I need more features in the component.

Now, the code consists in a module that has two directives. A "typeahead" and the "popup". The problem is that when I update the model from the linking function of the typeahead, changes don't get reflected on the popup until it is clicked. The scopes seem to be fine, but the view, doesn't get rendered.

The test is like this:

1. Focus the text box.
2. Blur it.
3. Click on the gray box. - The log gets updated but it should have in step 1 and 2.
4. Click one of the items of the list. - The log gets updated
5. Focus and blur the text box - The log gets updated, but the view doesn't.
6. Click on the gray box. - The log shows what happened in the step 5.

What I'm I doing wrong? Should I take control over the digest cycle? however I wouldn't know how.

Additional information (you may skip this): The further features I'm after is showing a modal dialog when the user wants to create or edit a record on the list. They consist in quite a lot of inputs so I'm thinking in putting an edit button in each record and a create button inside the text box. The items in the list are bounded to records in the database and it will be heavily used throughout the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to "take over the digest cycle", but you do need to trigger it to run since you're binding events outside of the Angular context.

Just use `scope.$apply`:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.test.changingText += "focused\n";
});
```

[Fork of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vxS6RxeTMm5G98eseZ5S?p=preview)

[$apply docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)

Comment: Do you think the structure is ok? would you do what I'm after like this?.

Comment: Why you don't avoid the DOM manipulation by using a template for the `consLovFuentes` directive. Then you can use ng-blur, ng-focus, etc and avoid manual digest triggering.

Comment: Well, now that I think about it... I want the component to be as simple as posible and it should be an inline element. But now I remember that there is a display: inline; property which is why I didn't want to use the template. However, an <input cons-lov-fuentes> seems right because it is an input, not a div. I can't use the Element option because of IE10 support. Where would you put the modal dialog though? in the template aswell?

Comment: I suggest experimenting with using a template more and see what you come up with. The problems you describe don't add up. Also, what is the issue with IE **10** and templates which can't be surpassed? As for the modal, without too much analysis, I would bet that it would be best in its own directive with its own template.

Comment: DOM manipulation in Angular should be used only in a worst case scenario since it is of a different model (ie imperative, jQuery) than Angular, which meant to be declarative.